# Does t.reference :category actually replaces the belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

Lets say I have *Product < Category*, and a *Product* `belongs_to` *Category*
is having `t.reference :category` replacing the need for the `belongs_to` or `has_one` association ?
does it automatically generate the `category_id` in the table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`references` is just an alias for `belongs_to`. It's the same method. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/88aa2efd692619e87eee88dfc48d608bea9bcdb4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L429).

```
alias :belongs_to :references
```

It automatically generates the parent foreign key in the table. It has no bearing on the association declarations inside your models. You still have to write these exclusively. What both `references` and `belongs_to` are is a shortcut to adding the foreign key column.

Note that `belongs_to` here is in the context of migrations, and not the model association `belongs_to`.

Answer (score 0):

For ActiveRecord, one is just an alias for the other one.

`references` is the original method ([link to doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table/references)), and `belongs_to` is an alias for `references` ([link to doc](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table/belongs_to)).

Beware that there is another method `#references` of ActiveRecord which does different things ([link to doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references))